# EventHandler and ActionMenu

Tags: eventhandler

Here is the bit of code causing me issues:

```
{DynamicModule[{nothing},
  EventHandler[
   ActionMenu["Set x", {"x = 1" :> (x = 1;)}, Enabled -> True], 
  {"MouseClicked" :> (nothing++)}]], Dynamic[x]}
```

No matter how hard I try to click the `ActionMenu` does not open at all.

Removing the `{"MouseClicked" :> (nothing++)}` allows to open the `ActionMenu`:

```
{DynamicModule[{nothing},
  EventHandler[
   ActionMenu["Set x", {"x = 1" :> (x = 1;)}, Enabled -> True], 
  {}]], Dynamic[x]}
```

The aim of the code would be to `Enable`/`Disable` the `ActionMenu` after `x = 1` is clicked in this example.

What am I doing wrong in the first bit of code?

Comment: `DynamicModule[{x}, {EventHandler[
   ActionMenu["Set x", {"x = 1" :> (x = 1;)}, 
    Enabled -> Dynamic[x =!= 1]]], Dynamic[x]}]` Simple, but not sure if this is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `PassEventsDown -> True`:

```
{DynamicModule[{nothing = 0}, 
  EventHandler[
   ActionMenu["Set x", {"x = 1" :> (x = 1;)}, 
    Enabled -> True], {"MouseClicked" :> (nothing++)}, 
   PassEventsDown -> True]], Dynamic[x]}
```

Comment: I forgot the `PassEventsDown` option... It's so natural...

Comment: Thanks @ both of you. MichaelE2 strictly replies the "why it does not open" question and Silvia replies the "how to disable after one click" question. Since the main issue was to answer "why it does not open anymore" I've accepted this answer. But once again, thanks for you two :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
{DynamicModule[{flag = True},
               ActionMenu["Set x", {"x = 1" :> (
                                                flag = Not@flag;
                                                x = 1;)},
                Enabled -> Dynamic[flag]
                ]
               ],
 Dynamic[x]}
```

The `EventHandler` will take whatever it wraps around as mouse event trigger, and I think the `"MouseClicked"` event is hijacked by it so `ActionMenu` doesn't see the event.